# How can I combine physics and animation to make a believable death sequence?

Tags: unity, physics, animation, ragdoll

I am quite new to working with physics and rigidbodies. So far I've managed to push the body in the opposite direction from where they are hit by an arrow. But I am unsure of how I can combine this with a death animation and still have it look natural no matter what direction the body flies in, since I can only animate it in one direction (falling backwards).

Do I need to use ragdolls or is there another way?

My code to push:

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForceAtPosition(previousImpactDir * 500, previousImpactPos, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

Comment: If we are talking about realistic, a body hit by an arrow does not really fly that much back. Google tells something in the ballpark of about 100 joules of force.
For comparison, about the same as a sword blow. An air rifle would be about 30 joules; a pistol bullet 500 joules; a fist about 40 joules.

Comment: It sounds like you're describing what's often called an "[active ragdoll](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22active+ragdoll%22)" — modelling a body as jointed colliders that react to physics, but with forces to propel it in ways that look more alive than just a bunch of dead weights. This is a huge area of ongoing research, with many games using combinations of both physics simulation and multiple different death animations selected/blended based on hit position and impulse. A search through the GDC Vault or SIGGRAPH might be a good start for some inspirations about how others have attempted this.

Comment: thanks @DMGregory